# zend framework problem

Tags: zend-framework, installation

i want to install zend framework,i set my virtual hosts as the following :

Windows host setup :
`127.0.0.6  nolanalg`

xampp virtual host setup (httpd-vhosts.conf) :

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.6
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.6>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/nolanalg/public/"
ServerName nolanalg
</VirtualHost>
```

but i got an error!
it shows me this :

---

> Server error! The server encountered
> an internal error and was unable to
> complete your request. Either the
> server is overloaded or there was an
> error in a CGI script. If you think
>
> this is a server error, please contact
> the webmaster.
>
> Error 500 nolan
> 06/10/10 16:23:41 Apache/2.2.4 (Win32)
> DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8d
> mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.1

---

my OS is windows 7,i had uninstall my antivirus,and turned off my windows firewall.

what is the problem?

Comment: this is the complete error  : 


Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
nolan
06/10/10 16:23:41
Apache/2.2.4 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8d mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.1

Comment: What does your error.log say? I doubt this will be a ZF problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you create your virtual host same following code in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80


<VirtualHost mytest:80>
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mytest/public">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
     Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mytest/public"
    ServerName mytest
    ServerAlias mytest

</VirtualHost>
```

so in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc open host file

and add  foloowing line

```
127.0.0.1       mytest
```

instead 127.0.0.1 enter your IP